# How to change background color of youtube Player - youtube-iframe-api

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

When start playing my video on my website [jaideeppackers.in](http://jaideeppackers.in) there are black colour strips shown by the YouTube player on right and left.

I want to set it to white so that it merges with the background of my website.

It has nothing to do with option `theme=light` and `theme=dark`, so any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
.html5-video-player{
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: please 

elaborate bro

this is my code

<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FEh6BWzYHlU?rel=0?theme=light" style="background-color:#FFF" width="100%"></iframe>

how should i apply your code